# Dynamically switch the Dbcontext connection string in the Repository at runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Problem:  I have a set of databases with the same data structure, and tables.  I have a list of the servers, the catalogs, and the login info. I want to loop through the server list, and set the dbcontext connection string, so I can read data from the exact same table in each instance, and return a list of configuration info. I’m following the SOLID Principle Design using CQRS, and it's a .Net 7 solution that works fine.  Just wondering, if it’s possible to set the connection string at the repository level, when the data access occurs, and not have to register each instance, or keep it in the appsettings.  I can pass the connection string, but need to set it in the dbcontext.  Thanks for the help.

Sample DbContext class:

```
namespace DemoApp.Persistence.DomainDbContext;

public partial class DemoDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DemoDbContext(DbContextOptions<DemoDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }


    public virtual DbSet<ConfigSystem> ConfigSystems { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      
        modelBuilder.Entity<ConfigSystem>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.ConfigSystemGuid);

            entity.ToTable("ConfigSystem", "dbo", tb => tb.HasTrigger("Tr_ConfigSystem_Update"));

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.ConfigSystemName, "UX_ConfigSystem").IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.ConfigSystemGuid)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(newsequentialid())")
                .HasColumnName("ConfigSystemGUID");
            entity.Property(e => e.EnvironmentId)
                .HasMaxLength(250)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("EnvironmentID");
            entity.Property(e => e.EnvironmentType)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);
            entity.Property(e => e.Version)
                .HasMaxLength(25)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");
            entity.Property(e => e.VersionDate)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())")
                .HasColumnType("smalldatetime");
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}


**Sample Repository class:** 

namespace DemoApp.Persistence.Repositories
{
    public class ConfigSystemRepository : DemoAppBaseRepository<ConfigSystem>, IConfigSystemRepository
    {
        public ConfigSystemRepository(DemoAppDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
        {
        //How to rest the connection string on the dbcontext to point to the right server/database
        }

        private readonly string DemoConnectionString = Persistence.PersistenceServiceRegistration.ConntectionSting;

        public string GetDemoAppCn()
        {
            return DemoConnectionString ;
        }

        public async Task<List<ConfigSystem>> GetConfigSystemList()
        {
            return await _dbContext.ConfigSystems.Take(10).ToListAsync();
        }
     
        public async Task<ConfigSystem> GetConfigSystemItem()
        {
            return await _dbContext.ConfigSystems.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add the connection strings to an appsettings.json file, then read that file in a piece of middleware to set your connection objects prior to setting your default connection in your context. Something like IOptions can help you map your section to a concrete object to pass into your class constructors.

Comment: Thanks but I can't store the connection string in the appseting, per requirement.

Comment: A DbContext already is a multi-entity repository and Unit-of-Work. You're already passing the connection string dynamically at runtime in `AddDbContext`.

Comment: Gotta store it somewhere!

Comment: The problem is I need to loop through the list, and switch the database on each repository call.  The connection string cannot be stored in the settings.  It comes from a set of other calls that build the connection string. I need to register a single dbcontext, but switch connections per repository call.

Comment: You can already switch connections dynamically per "repository".  The problem is that static. There's absolutely no reason for this. No matter where you get the connection string from, you can pass it in `AddDbContext`. That factory method is executed every time a new DbContext is created.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm over simplifying your problem.  You build the connection string in the repository, can you pass the connection string to the method as a param?

```
public async Task DoRepositoryThing (string connStr)
{
  using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
  {
      //do you db stuff here
  }

}
```

Comment: I can pass the connection string just fine.  The question is when the method call occurs will the dbcontext accept a new connection string before the lambda call, and how to set it.

Comment: There's no reason to build anything inside the repository as the DbContext was already constructed dynamically with the connection string passed through `DbContextOptions<DemoDbContext> options`. The OP is trying to replace that dynamic connection string with a hard-coded one provided by a global static property, `Persistence.PersistenceServiceRegistration.ConntectionSting`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help! Here's part of the answer to my question. I wanted to switch the database connection at the data retrieval point, so I can access different databases, but with the same table. Wasn't sure if EF would allow you to switch at runtime.  Working on the ParallelForEachAsync method. Ran into concurrency issues. But, this works :)

```
    public List<DemoData> GetDemoDataList(string serverName, string dataSource) 
    {
     var conString = Persistence.PersistenceServiceRegistration.GetConString(serverName, dataSource); //call to a static method to build the string 
     _dbContext.Database.SetConnectionString(conString); //set the dbContext dynamically
     return _dbContext.DemoData.ToList(); //Tada!!! 
    }
```